# Displaying a field from a list on a second list where references are equal

Tags: list, join, hyperlink, linked-list

I have 2 content types and have a lookup from in the second
picking up the reference number from the first to relate them.

I'm wanting to display a status field in the second list showing the status of the record in the first list but need this to relate to the corresponding record.

What calculated query can I use to show this?

Example

List 1

```
CAPS ref - 12345
CAPS Status - in progress
```

List 2

```
CAPS Action ref - 12345 (lookup from list 1)
Complete Cap Status - in progress (calculated from list 1 where CAPS ref = CAPS action ref
```